# Mongoose - How to avoid data redundancy when sending Post request using ExpressJS?

Tags: express, mongoose

I'm learning the MEAN Stack while creating a Book Publisher System.
I'm quite new at programming and I researched a lot for the answer without success.

I want to send a Post request using Express and when Mongoose save the bookSchema.author I want it to save the first name and the last name in the authorSchema. And when I send a Get request to Mongoose I want to receive the book saved with the author saved in the authorSchema.

I have created 2 Mongoose Schemas:

Books schema:

```
    const bookSchema = new Schema ({
    name:{
        type    :String, 
        required: true},
    isbn:{
        type    :Number,
        min: 1000000000000,
        max: 9999999999999,
        required: true
    },
    price:{
        type    :Number, 
        required: true},
    page:{
        type    :Number, 
        required: true},
    author:{
        type    :String,
        required: true},
})
```

Authors schema:

```
const authorSchema = new Schema({
first_name:{
    type: String,
    required: true
},
last_name:{
    type: String,
    required: true
}})
```

And a Express Post function:

```
route.post('/addBook', (req, res)=>{
    let newBook = new book({
            name: req.body.name,
            isbn: req.body.isbn,
            price: req.body.price,
            page: req.body.page,
            author: req.body.author
    })
    newBook.save((err, bookSaved)=>{
        if (err){
            res.send(err)
        }
        else{
            const bookName = req.body.name
            res.send(bookName + ' salvo.')
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: You have to use [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) or make the author a [subdoc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) in the book.

Comment: I finally made it, @MikaS. Thanks a lot!